# Why is scanf() taking wrong input?

Tags: c, input, output, scanf

I am completely new to C, and was writing a small very simple program. The problem is that the `scanf()` is taking wrong input:-

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    int main(int args, char*argv[])
    {
       int num1 = scanf("%d",&num1) ; 
       int num2 =scanf("%d", &num2) ;
       printf("Num1 = %d\n", num1) ; 
       printf("Num2 = %d\n", num2) ; 
       return 0 ; 
    }
```

When I give 34 and 23 as input it is outputting:-

`Num1 = 1`
`Num2 = 1`
Why is it so?

Comment: Please use *manuals and documentation* to find out how any particular thing you're trying to use works. It's not productive or constructive to ask something so basic that has been documented much better elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll surely follow it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `scanf` returns the number of characters it matches. `scanf("%d",&num1)` and `scanf("%d",&num2)` will return `1`. You are assigning that number, i.e, `1` to `num1` and `num2`.
Now do it as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(int args, char*argv[])
{
   int num1;  
   int num2;
   scanf("%d",&num1) ;  
   scanf("%d", &num2) ;
   printf("Num1 = %d\n", num1) ; 
   printf("Num2 = %d\n", num2) ; 
   return 0 ; 
}
```

Suggested reading: [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 3.8](http://www.c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html).

Answer (score 4):

Don't assign the return value of `scanf` to `num1` and `num2`. The return value of `scanf` indicates if the scan is successful, not what you thought it was.

```
int num1, num2; 
scanf("%d", &num1); 
scanf("%d", &num2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the return value of scanf into your values. scanf returns how many characters it matched; you're already passing a reference to the variable you want scanf to store the result in.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assigning the return value of scanf into your num1 and num2?

My suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(int args, char*argv[])
{
   int num1, num2;  

   scanf("%d",&num1); 
   scanf("%d", &num2);
   printf("Num1 = %d\n", num1); 
   printf("Num2 = %d\n", num2); 
   return 0; 

}
```